# The Shahrukh question on imbd dataset, certainly is tricky

Tags: mysql

**

> The full question: The Shahrukh number of an actor is the length of
> the shortest path between the actor and Shahrukh Khan in the
> "co-acting" graph. That is, Shahrukh Khan has Shahrukh number 0; all
> actors who acted in the same film as Shahrukh have Shahrukh number 1;
> all actors who acted in the same film as some actor with Shahrukh
> number 1 have Shahrukh number 2, etc. Return all actors whose Shahrukh
> number is 2.

**

my SQL query:

```
#loading SQL module
%load_ext sql

#connect to the database
%sql sqlite:///Db-IMDB.db

%%time
%%sql

UPDATE Movie SET year = REPLACE(year, "I", "");
UPDATE Movie SET year = REPLACE(year, "V", "");
UPDATE Movie SET year = REPLACE(year, "X ", "");
UPDATE Movie SET title = LTRIM(title);
UPDATE Movie SET year = RTRIM(LTRIM(year));
UPDATE Movie SET rating = RTRIM(LTRIM(rating));
UPDATE Movie SET num_votes = RTRIM(LTRIM(num_votes));

UPDATE M_Producer SET pid = RTRIM(LTRIM(pid));
UPDATE M_Producer SET mid = RTRIM(LTRIM(mid));

UPDATE M_Director SET pid = RTRIM(LTRIM(pid));
UPDATE M_Director SET mid = RTRIM(LTRIM(mid));

UPDATE M_Cast SET pid = RTRIM(LTRIM(pid));
UPDATE M_Cast SET mid = RTRIM(LTRIM(mid));

UPDATE M_Genre SET gid = RTRIM(LTRIM(gid));
UPDATE M_Genre SET mid = RTRIM(LTRIM(mid));

UPDATE Genre SET gid = RTRIM(LTRIM(gid));
UPDATE Genre SET name = RTRIM(LTRIM(name));

UPDATE Person SET name = RTRIM(LTRIM(name));
UPDATE Person SET pid = RTRIM(LTRIM(pid));
UPDATE Person SET gender = RTRIM(LTRIM(gender));

%%time
%%sql

select distinct PID, 
Name 
from Person natural 
join M_Cast
where Name != ‘Shah Rukh Khan’ and MID in 
(select MID from M_Cast 
 where PID in 
 (select PID 
  from Person natural 
  join M_Cast
  where Name != ‘Shah Rukh Khan’ and MID in 
  (select MID
   from Person natural 
   join M_Cast
   where Name != ‘Shah Rukh Khan’)))and PID not in 
(select PID
 from Person natural 
 join M_Cast where Name != ‘Shah Rukh Khan’ and MID in 
 (select MID
  from Person natural 
  join M_Cast where Name = ‘Shah Rukh Khan’))
limit 7;
```

output: -- I a getting an error.

```
* sqlite:///Db-IMDB-Assignment1.db
(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "Rukh": syntax error
[SQL: select distinct PID, Name 
from Person natural 
join M_Cast
where Name != ‘Shah Rukh Khan’ and MID in 
(select MID from M_Cast 
 where PID in 
 (select PID 
  from Person natural 
  join M_Cast
  where Name != ‘Shah Rukh Khan’ and MID in 
  (select MID
   from Person natural 
   join M_Cast
   where Name != ‘Shah Rukh Khan’)))and PID not in 
(select PID
 from Person natural 
 join M_Cast where Name != ‘Shah Rukh Khan’ and MID in 
 (select MID
  from Person natural 
  join M_Cast where Name = ‘Shah Rukh Khan’))
limit 7;]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
Wall time: 51.7 ms
```

Schema:

[find the schema to the problem statement here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYlCa.jpg)

DB: [The DB link can be obtained here](http://sendanywhe.re/6HVPPIAR)

Need help. Thanks in advance.

**After editing from backticks to double-quotes on the strings::**

```
%%time
%%sql

select distinct PID, 
Name 
from Person natural 
join M_Cast
where Name != "Shah Rukh Khan" and MID in 
(select MID from M_Cast 
 where PID in 
 (select PID 
  from Person natural 
  join M_Cast
  where Name != "Shah Rukh Khan" and MID in 
  (select MID
   from Person natural 
   join M_Cast
   where Name != "Shah Rukh Khan")))and PID not in 
(select PID
 from Person natural 
 join M_Castwhere Name != "Shah Rukh Khan" and MID in 
 (select MID
  from Person natural 
  join M_Castwhere Name = "Shah Rukh Khan"))
limit 7;
```

**still facing error**

```
* sqlite:///Db-IMDB-Assignment1.db
(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "!=": syntax error
[SQL: select distinct PID, Name 
from Person natural 
join M_Cast
where Name != "Shah Rukh Khan" and MID in 
(select MID from M_Cast 
 where PID in 
 (select PID 
  from Person natural 
  join M_Cast
  where Name != "Shah Rukh Khan" and MID in 
  (select MID
   from Person natural 
   join M_Cast
   where Name != "Shah Rukh Khan")))and PID not in 
(select PID
 from Person natural 
 join M_Castwhere Name != "Shah Rukh Khan" and MID in 
 (select MID
  from Person natural 
  join M_Castwhere Name != "Shah Rukh Khan"))
limit 7;]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
Wall time: 6.98 ms
```

Just found out the **correct number of rows** for the solution is **25698** whereas, the above solution gives an output of **48 rows**. Need your help. Thanks

Comment: P.C.: I have been executing this on my python notebook. Have tried "row_number() over partition", which gives an error, found out that MySQL doesn't use that.

Comment: @AkshayKumar row_number and other window functions require mysql 8.0 or mariadb 10.2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just describing the logic, so the code below **will not run** on your schema.

You can get all actors who worked with Shahrukh Khan (SK=0) with

```
CREATE VIEW sk1 AS (                            /* SK=1 actors are... */
SELECT a1.id FROM actors AS a1                  /* ...those actors... */ 
  JOIN cast AS c1 ON (c1.actor_id = a1.id)      /* ...who casted... */
  JOIN cast AS sk ON (sk.film_id = c1.film_id)  /* ...in the same film cast... */
  JOIN actor AS a0 ON (sk.actor_id = a0.id AND a0.name = 'Shahrukh Khan')     /* as the actor, whose name is 'Shahrukh Khan' */
  WHERE a1.id != a0.id                          /* but are not him */
);
```

Now SK2 actors are among the other actors

```
CREATE VIEW oc AS (                             /* Other actors are... */
    SELECT c1.actor_id AS id FROM cast AS c1    /* ...those who casted... */ 
    LEFT JOIN sk1 ON (sk1.id = c1.actor_id)     /* ...related to actors in SK1... */
    LEFT JOIN actor AS a0 ON (c1.actor_id = a0.id AND a0.name = 'Shahrukh Khan')
                                                /* ...and the actors who are SK... */
    WHERE sk1.id IS NULL AND a0.id IS NULL      /* ...by not being there. */
) AS otherActors;
```

Actors who are in otherActors, and have casted with actors in SK1, have SK of 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
SELECT otherActors.id FROM otherActors AS oc
    JOIN cast AS c1 ON (oc.id = c1.actor_id)
    JOIN cast AS c2 ON (c1.film_id = c2.film_id)
    JOIN sk1 ON (c2.actor_id = sk1.id)
) AS sk2;
```

You will notice that there are some useless JOINs up there (I never need data from actor a1, as the data I get, a1.id, is by definition the same as c1.actor_id). It might come in handy if you need the names, though. Or you can do a further JOIN when (and if) you need actor information beyond their ID. I also never need data from the films. Using actor forces each actor to only be in the set once, though; if I had used cast straight away, then I might well have found repeating actor ID's, forcing me to add a `DISTINCT` clause.

Finally, this is a non-recursive, non-programmable implementation. SK=3 would force me to add another view and further complications. **MySQL 8.0+ has recursive CTE support**, which completely changes the game (you can adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query), but beware of loops; you want to add an explicit check so that the "next" set always fishes among actors with *no* SK number assigned).

Answer (score 0):

You are using backticks to enclose string literals; mysql requires either single or double quotes instead.  In mysql, backticks are used to quote identifiers that might otherwise conflict with reserved words, not string literals.

So replace every

```
‘Shah Rukh Khan’
```

with

```
"Shah Rukh Khan"
```

Comment: Firstly thank you. I have tried, but still getting error, I have updated the problem info. area above. Need your help.

Comment: Okay, I have got certain output after separating **"where"** clause in the code, I am not getting the correct answer for the problem statement. Can you please help me in getting the right solution for the above.